# getting nil value after converting it to the required Date.Function returning nil values

Tags: swift, xcode, date, nsdateformatter, swift5

In the below function Given ,I am getting nil value while converting it to the required date.

```
func convertdate(input:String) -> String
  {
      var date = Date()
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM,yyyy"
      let myString = formatter.string(from: date)
      let yourDate: Date? = formatter.date(from: input)
      formatter.dateFormat = "EEE d MMM yyyy"
      let updatedString = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)
      print(updatedString)
      return updatedString
  }
```

calling function like this convertdate(input:"23 Jul,2020")

Comment: I run your code and its worked without any modification.You better try with adding Locale(ex: "en_US_POSIX") to your formatter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the locale to a fixed value and you should return `nil` if the string cannot be converted.

```
func convertdate(input:String) -> String?
{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM,yyyy"
    guard let yourDate = formatter.date(from: input) else { return nil }
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEE d MMM yyyy"
    let updatedString = formatter.string(from: yourDate)
    print(updatedString)
    return updatedString
}
```

I removed the variable `myString` because it's unused.

Comment: now its not returning anything when call that function convertdate(input:"23 Jul,2020") ?? ""

Comment: now its not returning anything when called the function convertdate(input:"23,Jul 2020") ?? ""

Comment: The code should work, I tested it in a Playground. It returns `nil` if the Locale doesn't match `Jul` for the month name. And the comma must be between month and year.